# How to stop my dog from howling all through the night?

Tags: dogs, training, vocalizations

I noticed that for the past few day, my dog howls a lot in the night. I initially thought it was because I forgot to give him food before going to sleep but yesterday and the day before, I'm sure I did (and even left some extra food in his plate).

Yet, he still howled a lot throughout the night. What can I do to stop this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Researchers admit that howling behavior in dogs is still largely a
>   mystery. But if Fido goes wild at the sound of sirens or other dogs,
>   it's not because his ears hurt. It's his ancestry that's partly to
>   blame. (Source:[www.livescience.com](http://www.livescience.com/34616-why-dogs-howl-sirens.html))

So it can be response to some sound he hears. But we can only assume. Sometimes dogs also cry in howling sounds which can be due to some behaviorally problem like feeling lonely etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your dog is howling at night, that probably means he isn't sleeping. Is he a breed more prone to being nocturnal like a great pyrenees? Either way... Have you tried exercising him more or giving him more play time? A tired dog is much less likely to howl at night because he'll be sleeping. Puzzle toys are great for working your dog's brain and tiring him out that way. You can also try hiding your dog's dinner in small caches around the house and having him find it. This is a really fun engaging game that's tiring and rewarding.